# MYSQL INSERT INTO FROM SELECT UPDATE WHERE NOT EXIST

Tags: mysql, select, insert, duplicates, exists

My database structure is:

```
items (id, item_name)
user (id, username)
inventory(id, user_id FK, item_id FK, amount)
```

I have a select query which returns rows with (item_id, amount)

I just want to add values from that select query into that inventory table.
So what i need in pseudo code is:

```
FUNCTION give_items(IN in_user_id)

FOR EACH ROW FROM THAT SELECT:    
   IF ROW EXISTS with user_id = in_user_id AND item_id = SELECT.item_id THEN INSERT ROW
   ELSE UPDATE ROW amount = amount + SELECT.amount
```

it is like INSERT INTO SELECT ... ON DUPLICATE KEY, but i need to respect user_id and item_id not PRIMARY KEY

@EDIT
This is what i got now:

```
INSERT INTO `items_inventory` (`user_id`,`item_id`,`amount`)
SELECT mu.user_id, mi.item_id, SUM(mu.amount*mi.income) as amount_sum
FROM `mining_machines_users` AS mu
LEFT JOIN `mining_machines_income` AS mi ON mu.machine_id=mi.machine_id
WHERE mu.user_id=in_user_id
GROUP BY mi.item_id
ON mu.user_id=in_user_id AND mi.item_id=VALUES(`item_id`) //NEED FIX
`amount`=`amount`+VALUES(`amount`)
```

Sorry for my bad English, i hope that you will help me :)

Comment: Why are you shouting?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is the id property necessary? otherwise its maybe easier if you make a combined primary key of user_id and item_id

Comment: No, it's not necessary

Comment: If you make a combined key this will make sure that the user_id, item_id must be unique.

Comment: Can i return result of that select query inside insert ?

Comment: Yes that should be fine.